# Is there any step by step stuff to implement sentiment analysis and voice into my current Google Cloud Vision based face recognition app project?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, sentiment-analysis

I want to get an easy to understand guide to implement sentiment analysis and voice to my current project Cloud Vision project -object detection and face- besides. I downloaded kind of a sample, but it only recognized faces, but I want to implement custom sentiment analysis and add voice feature in real time using camera. Appreciate a lot guys!

I downloaded kind of a sample, but it only recognized faces, but I want to implement custom sentiment analysis and add voice feature in real time using camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Google offers a series of APIs to try to do what you want. You already know [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/overview/docs/), which indeed can detect emotions based on facial expressions.

Here you have a document from the [Chicago Coder Conference](http://www.chicagocoderconference.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/2017CCC-Vorhees-Are-you-happy-Google-Cloud-Vision-and-Speach-APIs.pdf) where they explain a series of products you can use to detect emotions, including [Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/) and [Cloud Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/overview/docs/) (the latter is for texts, though).

You could use Cloud Speech API and Natural Language API together to achieve what you want at this moment.